# convert raw byte data to h264 video using ffmpeg libs

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I have googled a lot but found no answers because they all use the command "ffmpeg xxxx" to do the job. I want to use the low level apis: `libavcodec`, `libavformat`...

the default format for android camera is `NV21(YUV420sp)`, and I want to encode the frames in camera preview to h264 video using the .so files. Is there any example for this?

Comment: You can use [javacv](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv) library for converting raw byte data to h.264 video

Comment: I know that, but the libs used in javacv cost too much (x86 and arm, opencv+ffmpeg, 40m+).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some samples inside the ffmpeg source that show how to encode video using the low level APIs, in `ffmpeg/doc/examples`.

The file you want to look at is `muxing.c`

It's a simple example that shows how to open audio and video streams, mux them and write it all out to a file. It generates a procedural test pattern for the video output and a sine wave for the audio, you can just change the fill_yuv_image() and get_audio_frame() functions to use your data, then replace the main() function with a JNI-exported function and you are almost done.